# How to disable Spartacus default calls

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is is possible to disable some of the default Spartacus calls?

After the user is logged in there are some calls that are made by default, but I do not need and would like to disable if possible.

These are the calls:

```
"...users/current", 
"...users/current/consenttemplates...", 
"...users/current/carts..."
```

The second and third one are made exactly after the login process and the first one is made after a page refresh or when navigating to different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by creating a custom interceptor and using `NEVER` from `rxjs`:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    /**
     * Deny list for calls we do not want to use from the Spartacus storefront
     */

    if (request.url.includes('consenttemplates') || request.url.includes('carts') || request.url.includes('users/current')) {
      return NEVER;
    } else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a workaround, and I advise you to use Cayacdev's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the related OccAdapter(s) and replace them in the providers array in a module. In your custom implementation you can leave the methods empty.

Here is described how: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cybersource-integration/#providing-a-custom-implementation-for-the-checkoutpaymentadapter